# Object properties return undefined after HTTP Request

Tags: json, http, get, request

I have the following code, which is attempting to get a local JSON file, containing an object, and return it to a variable `dataObj`:

```cs
const getRequest = async (url) => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const data = await response.json();
        return data;
    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
let dataObj = getRequest('http://localhost:5500/testJson.json');
console.log(dataObj);
```

My JSON file looks like this:

```json
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Kenny",
        "upcoming_events": [
             {}
         ]
    }
]
```

I can log the response to the console no problem, but whenever I try to access a property of `dataObj` I get 'undefined' returned.

This is a snippet of the console log for what is actually being returned by the request:

[image: Console log Snippet]

I have a feeling that it is returning a promise and not the actual object noted in the JSON file, is that right? However, I've done a fair bit of Googling and can't find specifically where I am going wrong. I am still very much an amateur, and I hope someone more experienced can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
const dataObj = getRequest('http://localhost:5500/testJson.json');
console.log(dataObj);
```

to:

```
getRequest('http://localhost:5500/testJson.json')
.then( dataObj => console.log(dataObj));
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps me get the actual json file logged to the console. The over-arching issue is that whenever I try and save the resolved value of the request (json object) to a variable, then try to access the properties of the object via the variable, they come back as undefined - thinking maybe this is due to Async? At a loss on how to do this.

Comment: @DarrenSmith you can't fix this. This is the nature of asynchronous programming (including promises). Instead of trying to fix this, try to come up with an application design that can work with async code correctly.